# what is the concept of "live container" in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In the answer of the following question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684917/what-questions-should-a-javascript-programmer-be-able-to-answer

I've got a question: what is "live" contianer? But I couldn't get any good reference on this topic by googling. Can you please describe the concept of "live container" in brief?

regards
Mahbubul Haque

Comment: You probably have to ask the one who used it. That's definitely not a generally used and/or accepted term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it refers to a [live NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#A_.22live.22_collection), that updates the results of the query automatically.

Comment: If the best answer you can give starts with "I'm guessing" there's a pretty good chance it's a bad question that shouldn't be answered.